# How to select two additional columns from another table based on values in the main table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `maintable` with 3 columns: `id`, `userid1` and `userid2`.

Another table named `users` is keyed by `userid`, and has `name` as a column.

**I want to select something along the lines of:**

```
SELECT maintable.*, users.name AS username1, users.name AS username2 
FROM maintable, users 
WHERE ...
```

Basically I want to get all the columns in the `maintable` row, and add two columns at the end that will draw the names for `userid1` and `userid2` from the `users` table.

I'm unsure how to format the where clause for a query like this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to join twice with users:

```
SELECT m.*, u1.name, u2.name
FROM maintable m 
INNER JOIN users u1 ON (m.userid1 = u1.userid)
INNER JOIN users u2 ON (m.userid2 = u2.userid)
```

You can read the documentation about MySQL JOIN Syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: What if the users table has only one entry for a particular user? I think left join would be preferrable.

Comment: @Cybernate: If that's the case (`userid1` or `userid2` might not exist in `users` table) I agree with you. Otherwise, I would prefer a **inner join**.

Comment: I don;t think there are two columns by name userid1 and userid2 in the table. It is just one column by name userid.

Comment: @Cybernate: how come? OP stated on the first sentence that, and I quoute: *I have a table "maintable" with 3 columns: `id`, `userid1`, `userid2`*

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz, yes, the maintable has two different userid columns

Comment: @CP1985: did you try the query I suggested?

Comment: @Pablo, yes, but I must be doing something stupid. It keeps returning unknown table "maintable", even though that table clearly exists and I can select from it

Comment: @CP1985: try with `m.*` instead of `maintable.*` (I updated my answer).

Answer (score 9):

something like this,

```
select m.*,
(select u1.name from users as u1 where m.userid1 = u1.userid) as username1,
(select u2.name from users as u2 where m.userid2 = u2.userid) as username2
from 
maintable as m
```

Comment: Don't forget to alias the users tables in the subqueries.

Comment: So it there a table with name `maintable` or it is a custom table?

Comment: @Mr_Green its already being mentioned in question that `maintable` is the tablename. pls read the question.